# Single dropdownlist value is getting selected for multiple dropdownlists

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function () {
    $("#CountryId").change(function () {
        $("#StateId").empty();
        $("#CityId").empty();
        var selectedItem = $(this).val();
        var ddlStates = $("#StateId");
        var statesProgress = $("#states-loading-progress");
        statesProgress.show();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url:'@Url.Action("GetStatesByCountryId")',
            data: { "countryId": selectedItem },
            success: function (data) {                       
                ddlStates.html('');
                $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                    ddlStates.append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));
                });
                statesProgress.hide();
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve states.');
                statesProgress.hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
    $(function () {
        $("#StateId").change(function () {
            $("#CityId").empty();
            var selected = $("#StateId").val();
            var ddlCities = $("#CityId");
            var cityprogress = $("#cities-loading-progress");
            cityprogress.show();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCitiesByStateId")',
                data: { "stateId": selected },
                 success: function (data) {
                     ddlCities.html('');
                     $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                         ddlCities.append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));
                     });
                     cityprogress.hide();
                 },
                 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                     alert('Failed to retrieve cities.');
                     cityProgress.hide();
                 }
             });
         });
       });
});</script>@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.CountryId)
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, Model.AvailableCountries, new  {style="width:150px;" })    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateId)
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, Model.AvailableStates,new  {@class="hello", style="width:150px;" })
 <span id="states-loading-progress" style="display: none;">Please wait..</span>
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityId)
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityId, Model.AvailableCities,new  {@class="hello1",style="width:150px;" })<span id="cities-loading-progress" style="display: none;">Please wait..</span>
```

Now here I have 3 dropdownlist. if I select dropdownlist1 I should get Countries and I am getting that and accordingly I should also get states in second dropdownlist. Well it's fine till here but when I am trying to get cities I am not getting concerned cities according to states .I am using MVC4 and Json methods as I can see when I am debugging the code it is supplying country id to instead of supplying state id to get cities when state dropdownlist is clicked. Plz help me I am new to jquery.
All the code within MVC is fine. Thanks

Comment: Could you please share some relevant HTML and your relevant controller methods that return the JSON

Comment: Why have you wrapped you functions in `$(function () {`? Its already inside `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Can you debug and see if the  $("#StateId").change(function () { is being hit add something like console.log("stateid changed"); and see if you get inside the function, it is also advisable to use classes instead of IDs as Id can change depending on how you built your html. better check the ID first

Comment: I am new to jquery and even if I put it in $(function() by removing  $(document).ready() The same thing plz I want to retrieve var selected = $("#StateId").val(); plz help me

Comment: Is this the only javascript on the page?

Comment: given a class name and tried still same thing is continued.

Comment: Do your generated DropDownLists have the ID in the generated HTML? I really doubt it. Please, check the generated HTML, and see if the ID is present in all the `<select>` tags. If not include it in the razor. I'm surprised that even the first DDL works fine.